# Record saved confirmation message

Tags: ms-access, save, messagebox

MS ACCESS: I have a 'save record' button on one of my forms. When clicked, I want it to show a confirmation message box saying something like "Your loan is approved", only if it saves the record without any error messages. Is this possible?

Comment: Validate the value(s) before saving, and you'll never see an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use error handling to do what you want if you place your code in an event procedure. When there is an error the message you set in the error handler will be displayed not the record saved message. Basic error handling would look like:

```
Private Sub SaveButton()
On Error GoTo PROC_ERRORHANDLER

    //////Your Save Code//////

    MsgBox "Record Saved", vbInformation, "Save"

    Exit Sub

PROC_ERRORHANDLER:

    MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical

End Sub
```